# Oracle SQL - Using joins to find values in one table, and not another

Tags: sql, oracle

Because apparently everyone hates sub selects, I would like to do this using joins.

For an incredibly contrived example, take two tables, one with a list of numbers from 1-6 and one with a list of even numbers from 0-8. Then, my goal would be to output all odd numbers in the table Nums.

```
Table Nums
Number
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six

Table Even
Number
Zero
Two
Four
Six
Eight
```

If I just wanted to get the list of even numbers that are in Nums, I'd do...

```
select nums.number
FROM nums,
     even,
where nums.number = even.number;
```

But, how can I use these tables to get the list of non-evens in the table Nums? Or, in other words, something like...

```
select nums.number
from nums
where nums.number not in (select number from even);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SubSELECTs are fine when used appropriately... "someone does not like something" alone is not a good enough reason IMHO.

There are several options - just 2 as examples:

```
SELECT nums.number FROM nums 
LEFT OUTER JOIN even ON even.number = nums.number 
WHERE even.number IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT nums.number FROM nums
MINUS
SELECT even.number FROM even
```

Comment: @Jeremy If you ever need to do that with SQL Server then use EXCEPT which is the same thing as MINUS for Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

for Oracle :

```
select nums.number
  FROM nums,
       even
 where nums.number = even.number(+)
   and even.number is null;
```

for ansi SQL:

```
SELECT nums.number
  FROM nums LEFT OUTER JOIN even ON nums.number = even.number
 WHERE even.number IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for the oracle syntax. I still don't know how to read the other syntax.

Comment: ansi SQL is also works on Oracle, besides it also work on other DBs. I offer you to use the second one because it is not vendor specific, if your DB changes your sql will still work, however if you use Oracle specific sql statements you may need to review your code while changing DB.