# two SQL tables with 2 columns in common, need records that are in table A but not in table B (column 1 is same in both but different column 2)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, tableA and tableB.
They both have columns (vehicle_make and vehicle_model).

I need all make/model of the vehicles from tableA that are not present in tableB.

Basically I need to find new make and models. tableB is currently I am using in my project and tableA is generic data with all the vehicles in the US.

Comment: Left join both tables. Then group by the columns. Then, select the count(*). Use the `HAVING` clause to filter all rows where the count is exactly one. Wrap this statement into another select, which finally returns the columns you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL - Using joins to find values in one table, and not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206962/oracle-sql-using-joins-to-find-values-in-one-table-and-not-another)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_make, vehicle_model
FROM tableA
WHERE (vehicle_make || vehicle_model) NOT IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT (vehicle_make || vehicle_model)
       FROM tableB)
```

Comment: Concatenating `vehicle_make` and `vehicle_model` like that is generally a bad idea - it may lead to false positives. `'a' || 'bc' = 'ab' || 'c'` even though the pair `('a', 'bc')` does not match `('ab', 'c')`. The immediate reply ("but in this case it is unlikely that this will happen.....") is also incorrect - one should not rely on the specifics of the data to justify code that is potentially buggy. Not to mention that indexes on the columns involved cannot be used if the `WHERE` clause (join condition, etc.) is written that way.

Comment: Usually a delimiter is added in concatenation which ensures there are no false positive. I will update post anyways.

Comment: Concatenation used that way is a bad idea regardless - with or without "delimiters". Why not just check that a tuple is in a set of tuples? That does work in Oracle SQL (and is probably part of the standard).

Answer (score 0):

Using a coorlated subquery: usually the most efficient with exists.

```
SELECT vehicle_make, vehicle_model
FROM tableA A
WHERE Not Exists (SELECT * 
                  FROM tableB 
                  WHERE A.vehicle_make = B.Vehicle_make
                    and A.vehicle_model = B.Vehicle_model
```

Using an outer join (if you needed data from table B on the records that did exist... like a count of records from B for each make/model

```
SELECT A.vehicle_make, A.vehicle_model, count(B.*)
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
 on A.vehicle_make = B.Vehicle_make
and A.vehicle_model = B.Vehicle_model
WHERE B.Vehicle_make is null
GROUP BY A.vehicle_make, A.vehicle_model
```

`In` works (unless you can have null values)

Comment: Correlated subqueries are generally slow, because they are calculated once for each row from `tableA` (because for each row in `tableA` the subquery is **different**). Luckily the Oracle optimizer is usually clever enough to rewrite the solution with `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` as an anti-join, making the solution much faster. At least since the last two or three versions of Oracle, there has been no difference between `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` (due to improvements in the optimizer).

Comment: The "rule of thumb" for in vs exists: BIG outer query and SMALL inner query = IN. SMALL outer query and BIG inner query = WHERE EXISTS. Remember -- thats is a RULE OF THUMB and rules of thumb always have infinitely many exceptions to the rule. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Comment: Brilliant reference to what was the right answer - for Oracle 8.1! By "at least since the last two or three versions of Oracle" I meant since Oracle 10.1 or so. Tom's answer was 100% correct - 17 years ago when he wrote it.

Comment: I love getting your goat :P

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from TableA a
left outer join TableB b 
       on a.vehicle_make = b.vehicle_make 
      and a.vehicle_model = b.vehicle_model
where b.vehicle_make is null
```